# Object Exporter + VS community 2013 =?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Do you guys know if  Object Exporter (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6a21c68-f815-4895-999f-cd0885d8774f) can be used for Visual Studio Community 2013?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing indicates that it shouldn't.

Comment: I interpret that you have installed object exporter in VS community 2013?

Comment: Nope, I run enterprise, but the community edition basically is the same as professional. It supports most extensions, only those that depebd on enterprise features won't work, and those are very rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly to install it in VS community 2013